# Enable the display of line numbers in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, line-numbers

Why doesn't Visual Studio have any way of showing line numbers in a source file? Is there any way to enable it, or a plugin for it? I know that the number of lines of code in a program doesn't matter, but sometimes it is nice to know how long a program is or the number of a particular line for reference.

Though I tried, I can't seem to find a way to enable line numbering and I find that surprising.

This is Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. (If you have read my older questions, I've been using 2008 Express until now.)

Answer (score 246):

Visual Studio has line numbering:

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> check the "Line numbers" checkbox.

Comment: You should check "Show All Settings" check box at the bottom of options window to see "line number" check box

Comment: Still hidden for SCSS files?!

Comment: If the "Line numbers" check box is checked and you still don't see the lines, uncheck the check box, click OK, the go back to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages, now check the "Line numbers" check box again and the lines should appear.

Comment: in VS 2017 my line numbers disappeared at some point, even though the tools/options check showed them selected. As @TH Todorov stated, I had to go back, uncheck, then recheck them and save for them to reappear.

Comment: In VS 2017 settings the square filled checkbox indicates partial application of a setting. It wasn't until I toggled the line numbers setting off and back on that it showed a normal checkmark and line numbers actually engaged for *all* languages.

Answer (score 46):

As of Visual Studio 2015, you can find the option under:

`Tools-> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages-> General -> Line Numbers`

[image: Visual Studio 2013 Line Numbers Option Menu]

---

Or simply go to `tools -> options` and type on the **search bar**: "Numbers".

Comment: I don't have a search bar in `tools -> options` menu.  How can I make it appear?

Answer (score 25):

Tools -> Options -> Show All Settings -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> Line Numbers

Answer (score 19):

In Visual Studio 2013 & 2015 :

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> check Line Numbers 
[image]

Answer (score 8):

It's not enabled by default but you can enable it by going to:

1. Click Tools
2. Options
3. Text Editor (expand)
4. All Languages
5. Line Numbers (Checkbox)
6. Click Ok

[settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbQNw.png)

Answer (score 5):

In VS 2010:

Tools > Settings > Expert Settings

Then:

Tools > Options > Show all settings > Text editor > C# > General > Check Line Numbers (checkbox)

Answer (score 5):

Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> Line Number checkbox
[image]

Comment: For my VS 2013, "Options..." was listed at the bottom of the "TOOLS" pull-down.

Answer (score 3):

Visual studio 2015 enterprice

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> check Line Numbers

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165340.aspx[image]

Answer (score 1):

Line numbers are not on by default.  To turn on line numbers just go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> General -> Display and check Line numbers:

http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/zainnab/WindowsLiveWriter/TurnonLineNumbers_A5E7/image_thumb.png

Answer (score 1):

For me, line numbers wouldn't appear in the editor until I added the option under both the "all languages" pane, and the language I was working under (C# etc)... [screen capture showing editor options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0is0y.png)

Answer (score 1):

Type 'line numbers' into the Quick Launch textbox (top right VS 2015), and it'll take you right where you need to be (tick Line Numbers checkbox).

Answer (score 1):

You should edit "settings.json". In that add, `"editor.lineNumbers":"on",` . You can check comments for various options you have.

In Visual Studio Code - 2017, you can also directly go to a given line number. There are following three ways to do that.

1. Directly use keyboard shortcut - Ctrl + G.
2. Under menu Go, use Go to Line - Go > Go to Line
3. Search for Go to Line in Command Pallete (Cmd + Shift + P).

Answer (score 0):

For MS Visual Studio 2015 type "Text" in Quick Launch (Ctrl+Q) of top right corner.
1) [quicklaunch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmPF1.jpg)

2) In the list select Text Editor->All Languages->General
[select_allLanguages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmzqP.png)

3) Now check on "Line Numbers" and click OK to get the line numbers.

Finally we get the line number in text editor.

Comment: You can also just type 'Line Numbers' in the quick launch to go directly to the right screen

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2010 Express, there is an option called "**Show all Settings**". Located at "**Tools > Options**", window.

[image]

If this option is not checked, the line number option will not be available. Make sure this option is checked like shown below. This will make lot of additional settings visible in the tree view to the left.

[image]

Now this will make the option "**Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > General > Line Editor**" available. Check the "**Line Number**" option to make line numbers visible on Visual Studio 2010 Express.

[image]